# How can I make ubuntu 14.04 virtual machines to use host machine JDK, SDK, JRE?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, sharing

I am looking for a way to make it possible for virtual machines mainly *ubuntu 14.04* VMs to be able to use host machine's JDKs, SDKs and any other Runtime Environments for example JRE(Java Runtime Environment).

How can I make it possible ?

### Comment and Answer

> Ubuntu 14.04 is long past end of life and therefore off topic here

this is one of the main reasons that I'd like to make a common ground for versions that have reached to end of life. because, regular servers do not provide facilities to download and update packages and makes a lot of troubles installing packages for each VMs.

> The best solution would be to upgrade your vm's to a supported version

This is a good idea when we want to install single OS at single machine. on the other words, if we need 10 VMs to concurrently run, it can be achieved by ubuntu 14.04 but when I upgrade to ubuntu 18.x.x at most 3 VMs can be run. so there is not any chance to run 10 VMs even on Modern Individual Systems.

Comment: Seems like a Virtual Machine, which is built on the idea of complete isolation, might be the wrong tool.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is long past end of life and therefore off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ... The whole idea with virtual machines are that you run a guest-OS on top os, and isolated from, the host-OS.

And even if you found a way to break the isolation, you can't be sure that the updated packages from the host-OS will run in the guest. because of version differences.

The best solution would be to upgrade your vm's to a supported version.

Comment: Thanks for your post. please see update.